# Toolbar within view with TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT

Tags: android

I'm adding view to screen from service. Is there any way to implement interface or set some listener to control onCreateOptionsMenu and so on?

Comment: What do you mean by "_adding view to screen from service_" ? That you have a service running and you add a view to an Activity in the Foreground?

Comment: @PRA mWindowManager.addView(mFloatView)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are showing a `Dialog` from service. You can use option menu and its methods in Dialog also. So create a custom Dialog class. And use `onCreateOptionMenu()`

**[Here](http://adnan.chohdry.com/android/android-how-to-implement-option-menu-in-activity-or-dialog/)**  is a good blog for making menu in Dialog.

**Just a suggestion:**

- Don't use `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` permission, which is asked from user. Instead you can make an Activity that looks like a Dialog. And to start that Activity. You don't need to 
  set `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` permission.

Comment: No. I have custom view inflated from xml. It was an activity, but it was rewritten to service to make the float view. In fact this view is extension for Android system implemented through Xposed API.

Comment: I linked a tutorial, does that help you?

Comment: Are you joking? It requires Activity instance. I have no Activity and I can't use it because I need to interact with underlying app.

Comment: I did not notice that, I'll edit my answer with solution.

Comment: When will you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Implement `View.OnClickListener` in your `Service` class like in this tutorial [here](http://www.androhub.com/android-floating-widget-like-facebook-messenger-chat-head/).